# No icons or launcer appears after login. I have tried everything

Tags: unity, login, compiz, launcher, icons

So after login the screen doesn't show any icons or anything else,its just background. I did some google searching and also on this site and i found this solution [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) . But the first solution doesn't do any good.

export DISPLAY=:0
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

and then

setsid unity

The above one however restored the icons and all but i couldn't open any drives and i face the same problem after restart. Please help I don't want to switch to windows or anything.
P.S. I am noob

Comment: Have you tried other solutions on that post ? For instance logging in to console and `rm -rf ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1` ?  Also, if you really need GUI right now, make sure you are connected to internet, go to console and try to install  another GUI, for instance `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell` or `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` . Once installed , run `sudo service lightdm restart` and on the login screen select the newly installed interface from a white cirle next to your username.

Comment: so, you enabled the unity plugin and it did no good?

Comment: @mchid yes i enabled plugin and it did nothing good.

Comment: @Serg Thank you for replying. I tried to remove the compiz-1 but it did nothing. So i installed gnome-shell and an interface popped up and i selected lightdm then i restarted lightdm and nothing happened on the screen. restarting also doesn't help.

Comment: @tanay are you on the site right now ?

Comment: @Serg yes serg .

Comment: Ok, I'm going to ask for a chat room. Users with under 20 reputation points cannot join chat. I'm going to need assistance from a mod to get you there. I'm interested in this question , so for discussion purposes we need a room. Ill let you know once it's ready

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32261/discussion-on-question-by-tanay-no-icons-or-launcer-appears-after-login-i-have).

Answer (score 0):

I have ubuntu 16.04 and these are the steps that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install –reinstall ubuntu-desktop

sudo apt-get install unity

rm -rf ~/.cache/compizconfig-1

sudo shutdown -r now
```

hope it helps!